# View Matrix from Camera in Unity Script

Tags: unity, matrix, view

I am looking to get a Camera component's "view" matrix in a script. I see that I can get the projection matrix using [Camera.projectionMatrix](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera-projectionMatrix.html), but I don't see a Camera.viewMatrix property...

I want these matrices in a script for a 3D graphics refresher tutorial that will visualize a camera's view and projection transforms in the form of game objects (representing vertices) that can be moved around the scene.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Camera.worldToCameraMatrix](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera-worldToCameraMatrix.html) *is* the transform that is commonly referred to as the "View" matrix. After transforming some vectors using this and the projection matrix, I am getting the exactly results that I was expecting. Awesome. :)